# How to play Media player after backing from another activity?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The Media Player work well when I start the app and click the button. However, when I hit the Home button or when I go to another activity and then I cannot play Media file any more when I come back to the MainActivity. Here is my code:

```
public void playMedia(View view){

    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    }
    else
        mp.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SOSPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SOSPlayer.seekTo(0);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SOSPlayer.stop();
    SOSPlayer.release();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SOSPlayer.stop();
}
```

Comment: Start the player within onResume().

Answer (score 0):

I thing you call playMedia method on layout as:

```
<Button
...
android:onClick="playMedia"
..
/>
```

What you need is to play that media again after getting back from previous activity .. you need to start that activity for result with startActivityForResult and listen to feedback onActivityResult to play the media  again. Here is a simple implementation:

```
    private static final int REQUEST_ID = 0x0001;
    private void startActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DifferentActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID:
                playMedia(null);
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```